# Anaconda Navigator can't update Idex

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

When I am in the Anaconda Navigator GUI (Version 1.9.7, macOS Mojave 10.14.6) I can't update the index using the button `Update index` next to `channels` in the `environments` tab.

The only thing which happens is that I Anaconda Navigator will get stuck at

```
Loading packages of /anaconda3
```

I can't cancel this process (it will just simply continue) and nothing basically happens. When I try to quit Anaconda Navigator I will get a warning that it is still busy.

In addition I lost the icon of `qtConsole` on the start page, which was the actual reason why I tried to update the index in the first place (it will start from the command line though).

**I already tried**: updating anaconda and all packages, restart everything

Is there anything else I can try, like updating the index from the command line (couldn't find anything so far)?

Comment: Which channel is configured? "defaults"? are you using navigator or cmd?

Comment: @PWillms Well, I was using the gui. At some point it must have started to work again, probably after updating to catalina or so. But honestly, I stopped using the gui all together since it was just to buggy and almost exclusively to the conda prompt.